# How to disable specific screen transition in react-navigation ^3.13.0

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I was trying to disable the screen transition for specific screen,

but I am not able to disable it

```
const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator(
    {
        ... Other routes

        CreditCardsList: {
            screen: CreditCardsList,
            navigationOptions: ({ navigation,screenProps }) =>({
                title: 'Credit Cards List',
                animationEnabled: false,
            }),
            transitionConfig: () => ({
                transitionSpec: {
                    duration: 0
                },
            }),
        },
    }
);

const App1 =  createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
export default App1;
```

**Version:**

```
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.60.5",
    "react-navigation": "^4.3.1",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^1.4.0",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^1.2.0",
```

I have tried almost everything, please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
        navigationOptions: {
                ...
        }
        defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
            let animationEnabled = true;

            if (navigation.state.routeName == 'CreditCardsList') {
                animationEnabled = false;
            } else if (navigation.state.routeName == 'OtherBlockedPage') {
                animationEnabled = false;
            }

            return {
                animationEnabled
            };
        }
```

Comment: It's giving routeName undefined

Comment: animationEnabled is not working, I think Its not for defaultNavigationOptions

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved as follow, please post if you have better option

```
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
        ...
    },
    transitionConfig: (navigation) => {
            if(navigation.navigation.state.routes.length > 2){
                if(navigation.navigation.state.routes[2].routeName === 'CreditCardsList'){
                    return{
                        transitionSpec: {
                            duration: 0,
                        },
                    }
                }
            }
```